# Return the closest matching object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about finding object in array. I have a array with objects like this:

```
var myArray = [{ index: 20, value: -1800000 }, { index: 21, value: -1200000 }, { index: 22, value: -10000 }, { index: 23, value: -1000 }, { index: 24, value: 0 }, { index: 25, value: 1000 }, { index: 26, value: 10000 }, { index: 27, value: 1800000 }];
```

and now the question is, how to return index of element where value is == 0 or if element with value == 0 do not exist return the first index of object with the smallest positive value.
I don't need a sort array, I only want to get one index of best match with value equal zero or close to zero but not negative.

Comment: use `Array.find`: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find . `.find` will return the **first occurrence** of the object matching the criteria provided to the anonymous function. If find returns undefined, no elements with 0 is found, hence you perform the second search, which is likely a find once again if you don't need any kind of sort. If you need to get the **closest to 0**, however, you likely need to use either sort either filter and sort.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use find, if that doesn't find something, loop the sorted array and return the first positive match:

```js
var myArray = [{ index: 20, value: -1800000 }, { index: 21, value: -1200000 }, { index: 22, value: -10000 }, { index: 23, value: -1000 }, { index: 24, value: 6 }, { index: 25, value: 1000 }, { index: 26, value: 10000 }, { index: 27, value: 1800000 }];

function findClosestToZero(arr) {
    let r = arr.find(v => v.value === 0);
    if (r) return r.index;
    arr.sort((a,b) => a.value > b.value);
    for (let o of arr) {
        if (o.value > 0) return o.index;
    }
}

console.log(findClosestToZero(myArray));
```

If your array is already sorted by the value,

```
 let r = arr.find(v => v.value >= 0);
```

would do it too. (Or you always sort the array first, but if you should do that depends a bit on the data)

Comment: Why not use `filter` right after the `sort`?

Comment: Maybe another find @Xufox

Comment: Whoops, I meant `find`. You could chain it right after `sort`.